# git add -p and trailing whitespace

Tags: git, whitespace

Very often when I run `git add -p`, I get warnings like this:

```
<stdin>:10: trailing whitespace.
... line of code ...
<stdin>:18: trailing whitespace.
... line of code ...
warning: 2 lines added whitespace errors.
```

What is really strange about this, is that the lines mentioned do NOT have trailing whitespace. If there is, git shows the space as a red square.

What is going on ?

Note: I'm using git version 2.13.2 with Cygwin on Win 10.

Comment: Do you get these warnings for all lines that you changed or added?

Comment: No just for some lines.

Comment: You could see which bytes are at the end of the concerned lines by executing `od  -t ax1 yourfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, linebreaks are CR-LF (two bytes), in Unix, linebreaks are LF. My guess: git complains about the CR as additional whitespace.